# Converting column values to range from 1-100

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My dataset contains population size for different states. Is it possible to convert them to a scale of 1-100.

```
Andaman And Nicobar 598
Andhra Pradesh  1,837
Arunachal Pradesh   1,178
Assam   2,228
Bihar   5,504
Chandigarh  140
Chhattisgarh    2,294
Dadra And Nagar Havel   149
Daman And Diu   168
Goa 108
Gujarat 3,077
Haryana 3,729
Himachal Pradesh    1,524
```

Comment: Sure; use ``=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)``.  Oh, is that not what you meant?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You mean to say Population share in Percentage in regard of the Highest population or in regard or Country's population?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm assuming that you have Data in Range `B2:B14`.*

Write this Formula in Cell `C2` & fill down.

```
=ROUND(100*B2/MAX(B$2:B$14),2)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help you @GhoseBishwajit ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Find the biggest population.. from your list. ->  5,504

Step 2 : for each line eg. Andaman, do : `<ThisCityPolupation>/<MaxPopulation*100`

--> (598)/(5,504)*100 = [ your ans for andaman.] = 10.86

--> Turn these into excel formula based on your cell location, apply.

Step 3 :  repeat it for every other line. done.

Hope it helps..